# Set environment variable with cron. Not working

Tags: variables, cron, environment-variables

How can I set for example with cronjob

```
1/* * * * * bash -c 'export TZ=Europe/London'
1/* * * * * bash -c '. /path/to/script.sh'
```

This script has multiple exports which is getting the timezone offset and would like that cronjob update the system var TZ with that one.

If I run it from shell it works with
`". /path/to/script.th"` as source but not in a cronjob.

At least how to set the environment variables with cronjob.

I also have tried that the script writes into the /etc/environment
TZ=Europe/London
and cronjob to `set -a;. /etc/environment; set +a;`

None are working but they do from shell.

Here is my script. What are my options from here when the script is ran by cronjob or anything else...Also tried to make it run with supervisord...same result.

Everything is working running locally from shell, but can't figure out how to modify the system "$TZ" environment with a script or from cronjob.

The script writes into the /etc/environment but when I set it from cron still won't update but it will from shell.

I know it all works from current shell but /etc/environment should be available to all.

I have edited so the way to go is write with the script into the /etc/profile.d/custom.sh

This works also inside a docker container to update periodicaly environmental variable if needed.

```
#!/bin/bash
#######################
## Preload variables ##
#######################

. /etc/profile
. ~/.bash_profile
. ~/.bashrc

#############################
## Get Boardtime from  API ##
#############################

boardtime=$(curl -s http://server/api/get-time \
                -u user:pass \
                -d locale='en_US' | \
                grep -oP '(?<=boardTime":")[^","boardTimeLocalized"]*' | \
                sed -r -e 's/^.{8}/& /' -e 's/[^ ]{2}/&:/5g' | \
                sed 's/:$//')
formatted_boardtime=$(date -d "$boardtime" "+%a, %e %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z")
echo -ne "\nLocaltime is $formatted_boardtime!\n"

###################################
## Get timezone offset from ship ##
###################################

minutes=$(curl -s http://server/timezone/currentOffset.txt | grep -oP "[-+][0-9]{0,9}/|[0-9]{0,9}")
echo -ne "\nTimezone offset is $minutes\n"
((h=$minutes / 60))

#############################
## Set Offset Symbol Value ##
#############################

symbol=$(echo $minutes | grep -oP "[-]")
digit=$(echo $h | grep -oP "[0-9]{2,4}")

if [[ $symbol == "-" ]] && [[ $digit ]]; then
    offset="-"$h"00"
elif [[ $symbol != "-" ]] && [[ $digit ]]; then
    offset="+"$h"00"
elif [[ $symbol == "-" ]] && [[ ! $digit ]]; then
    offset="-0$(echo "$h" | grep -oP '[0-9]{0,4}')00"
else
    offset="+0$(echo "$h" | grep -oP '[0-9]{0,4}')00"
fi

##########################
## Set Current timezone ##
##########################

localtime=$(echo $formatted_boardtime | sed -E "s/([-+][0-9]{4})$/"$offset"/")

if [[ $symbol == "-" && $offset == -1100 ]]; then
    export TZ="US/Samoa"
elif [[ $symbol == "-" && $offset == -1000 ]]; then
    export TZ="Pacific/Honolulu"
elif [[ $symbol == "-" && $offset == -0900 ]]; then
    export TZ="America/Nome"
elif [[ $symbol == "-" && $offset == -0800 ]]; then
    export TZ="America/Los_Angeles"
elif [[ $symbol == "-" && $offset == -0700 ]]; then
    export TZ="America/Denver"
elif [[ $symbol == "-" && $offset == -0600 ]]; then
    export TZ="America/Cancun"
elif [[ $symbol == "-" && $offset == -0500 ]]; then
    export TZ="America/Lima"
elif [[ $symbol == "-" && $offset == -0400 ]]; then
    export TZ="America/Santiago"
elif [[ $symbol == "-" && $offset == -0300 ]]; then
    export TZ="America/Bahia"
elif [[ $symbol == "-" && $offset == -0200 ]]; then
    export TZ="America/Noronha"
elif [[ $symbol == "-" && $offset == -0100 ]]; then
    export TZ="Atlantic/Azores"
elif [[ $symbol != "-" && $offset == +0000 ]]; then
    export TZ="Europe/London"
elif [[ $symbol != "-" && $offset == +0100 ]]; then
    export TZ="Europe/Berlin"
elif [[ $symbol != "-" && $offset == +0200 ]]; then
    export TZ="Europe/Athens"
elif [[ $symbol != "-" && $offset == +0300 ]]; then
    export TZ="Asia/Qatar"
elif [[ $symbol != "-" && $offset == +0400 ]]; then
    export TZ="Asia/Dubai"
elif [[ $symbol != "-" && $offset == +0500 ]]; then
    export TZ="Indian/Maldives"
elif [[ $symbol != "-" && $offset == +0600 ]]; then
    export TZ="Asia/Thimbu"
elif [[ $symbol != "-" && $offset == +0700 ]]; then
    export TZ="Asia/Bangkok"
elif [[ $symbol != "-" && $offset == +0800 ]]; then
    export TZ="Asia/Hong_Kong"
elif [[ $symbol != "-" && $offset == +0900 ]]; then
    export TZ="Asia/Tokyo"
elif [[ $symbol != "-" && $offset == +1000 ]]; then
    export TZ="Australia/Melbourne"
elif [[ $symbol != "-" && $offset == +1100 ]]; then
    export TZ="Pacific/Ponape"
elif [[ $symbol != "-" && $offset == +1200 ]]; then
    export TZ="Pacific/Fiji"
elif [[ $symbol != "-" && $offset == +1300 ]]; then
    export TZ="Pacific/Apia"
elif [[ $symbol != "-" && $offset == +1400 ]]; then
    export TZ="Pacific/Kiritimati"
fi

echo -ne "\nLocaltime is $localtime!\n"
echo -ne "\nTimezone matching offset is set $TZ!\n"

echo "$TZ" > /etc/timezone
echo "TZ=$TZ" > /etc/profile.d/custom.sh

###########################################################
## Restart postfix to apply new timezone also to postfix ##
###########################################################
/usr/sbin/postfix stop && /usr/sbin/postfix start
```

Comment: When you do `. SOMESCRIPT`, it sources the code in SOMESCRIPT in your present shell.  But when you run it in cron, it changes the environment for that cron execution.  There is no way to get cron to modify your environment.  It can only modify its own environment.  If you want to have certain environment values set for your cron job, add the appropriate lines in the script.sh file.

Comment: Hello @Nic3500, I have edited my post, maybe you can see what I mean.
What are my options to somehow update the "TZ" env on the system.
It is running on RHEL 8.6.

Comment: I run Linux Mint, the timezone is set in /etc/timezone.  For RHEL, look it up, I do not know.

Comment: Found a solution finally how to be able to write environment with cronjob.

For who needs it this works also inside docker container and will update the inside container cronjob the containers environment while running so it is a win-win.

The solution is create a /etc/profile.d/custom.sh

Inside there simply add all the environments you need like

export TZ=Europe/London
export etc..
..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can mark as a working solution for this using as follows then:

The solution is create a /etc/profile.d/custom.sh

Write in there you environment variable or your script can write in there and create the file with the content you need.
Inside there simply add all the environments you need like

```
export TZ=Europe/London
export MYENV=value
export etc..
..
```